# Redirecting Windows dialog error messages to console

Tags: windows, testing, command-line-interface

Does anyone know how to redirect/capture modal Windows error dialogs?  This is really problematic for non-interactive, command-line programs that are merely trying to run a program and capture the exit code and stdout/stderr output.

The most recent instance of this issue is a modal Windows dialog that has the following form:

> The program can't start because <foo.dll> is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

(Where the title of the modal GUI window is "System error")

Comment: This dialog is already suppressed for any process that you start from a .bat/.cmd file or from the command line prompt.  No diagnostic is available beyond the process exit code.  You can get some from enabling loader snaps but that's for debugging only: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't think that's true any more.  I've just checked on Windows 7 and a program launched from a batch file or from the command line prompt does generate the error dialog.  (Or perhaps it depends whether the failing executable is console vs. GUI?)

Answer (score 3):

These system error dialogs can be suppressed with [SetErrorMode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In that case, CreateProcess() should fail and GetLastError() should give you the corresponding error code.

Comment: How do you use this in node.js though?

Comment: How do you use that for stuff that happens before main() ?