# How to read Windows "System Error" message from Node.js child_process interface?

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line-interface

I am using [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) in Node.js to run a command-line program in Windows.  The command-line program could be misconfigured, causing it to be unable to launch.  When I attempt to launch the misconfigured program from the Command Prompt, I get a "System Error" *dialog box*: "The program can't start because (dll) is missing from your computer (...)"

[image: Screenshot of command line and error dialog]

### My question is: How can I read this error text from Node.js?

The child_process API offers access to error code, stdout, and stderr, none of which contain this error message, as the program never actually started.  I understand that this question is relevant:
[Redirecting Windows dialog error messages to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024579/redirecting-windows-dialog-error-messages-to-console)

Comment: You would need to use the Windows GUI API to find the window in question and read the text from it.  I don't know whether Node.js exposes that functionality.

Comment: If you can call `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)` that will prevent the child process from presenting the error dialog.  The exit code of the child process will indicate the problem, in this case 0xc0000135.

Comment: The nearest I could think of, is by using `tasklist` command and compare the Window Title. Use `tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq gm.exe - System Error"`. If  the %ERRORLEVEL% returns 1, the messagebox is shown.